# VS2017 - Project load failed - Duplicated linked item found in the project

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, csproj

I'm unable to get my project to load if an included Nuget package includes files that exist in my project.

My Nuget package contains a `appsettings.json` file, and since my project also has an `appsettings.json` file, I get the following error in Visual Studio 2017:

```
(load failed) - Duplicated linked item found in the project: "C:\users\user\.nuget\packages\mypackage\contentFiles\any\netcoreapp1.1\appsettings.json"
```

If I remove the appsettings file from my project (not the Nuget package), the project loads fine, but the file is needed for the project to work.

I can't seem to remove the appsettings file from the nuget package, but this might be my only option. 
'`dotnet pack`' seems to include this file even though my csproj file is not referencing it in the `"CopyToPublishDirectory"`

So the question is:
How to exclude certain files from being packaged (via `dotnet pack`)?
Or how to load a project where duplicated linked items exist?

Answer (score 4):

My set up is different from yours, but I got a similar error message when trying to add an existing project to a solution. I tried a few things, so not sure what exactly helped solved it in the end, but here's what I did:

- Cleaned the folder in which the project was located by deleting `bin` and `obj` folders
- Noticed that in the `csproj` file of the failing to load project there were a couple of `PropertyGroup` and `Item` nodes that were not used or were empty or pointing to folders that were not on the disk anymore, so I removed those nodes.

After that I removed and re-added the project to the solution and it loaded successfully.

Comment: Deleting bin and obj helped me.

Comment: It helped me too, but only temporarily.

Comment: Same story. Deleting `bin` and `obj` helped - probably I had there versions before the migration from project.json projects

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to work.
By default all content files are packaged. 
To disable this I edited the csproj file as follows:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <EnableDefaultContentItems>false</EnableDefaultContentItems>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appsettings.*"> 
      <Pack>false</Pack>
    </Content>
<ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be happening (among possibly other things) in projects which reference another project where there's a shared reference between the two.

For example:

```
Parent project [references package/dll X]
 |
 *-> Child, failing project [also explicitly references package/dll X]
```

In my case removing the X reference from the failed project helped solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, originally, clone to a new location fixed it. After it came bay I noticed in the csproj file

```html
<ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Helpers\" />
    <Folder Include="Styles\" />
    <Folder Include="Services\Interfaces\" />
    <Folder Include="Controls\" />
    <Folder Include="Styles\Fonts\" />
    <Folder Include="ViewModels\Base\" />
    <Folder Include="ViewModels\Product" />
    <Folder Include="ViewModels\Invoice\" />
    <Folder Include="ViewModels\Product\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\Product\Popup\" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

ViewModels\Product was referenced twice.